# why the console returns me classes is undefined when I have a class[ ] property in my establishment object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put my class object that I retrieve inside my classes array which itself is a property of my establishment object.

etablishments[]

```
$('#saveEstablishmentBtn').click(function() {
  
  let establishment = {
    name: $('#establishmentName').val(),
    neighborhood: $('#establishmentNeighborhood').val(),
    date: $('#establishmentDate').val(),
    classes:[]
  };
  if ($(this).text() === 'Enregistrer') {
    addEstablishment(establishment);
    
  } else {
    
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    establishments[index] = establishment;
    
  }
  
  updateTable();
  $('#establishmentModal').modal('hide');
  console.log(establishment);
  console.log(establishments);
    var indexc = $(this).data('index');
    var establishmentc = establishments[indexc]
  
    $('#saveClasseBtn').click(function() {

    var classe= {
      nameClasse: $('#classeName').val(),
      filiere: $('#classeFiliere').val(),
      profTitulaire: $('#classeProfTitulaire').val(),
    };
    if ($(this).text() === 'Enregistrer') {
      // addClasse(classe);

      if(establishmentc.classes === undefined){
        establishmentc.classes = [];
      }
       establishmentc.classes.push(classe); //here is the problem
      
      
    } else {
      var index = $(this).data('index');
      classes[index] = classe;
    }
  
    updateClasseTable();
    $('#classeModal').modal('hide');
    console.log(classe);
    console.log(classes);
   
  });
 
});
```

I don't understand why I have this error in the console. how to put class in classes? I make a two step crud. I save an establishment object inside a classes table then when I click on modify establishment a modal is displayed with the information of the establishment and a class table to add classes and a classes button when I click on add classes a second modal is displayed with a second modal I fill in and I save in the class table of the corresponding object

Comment: Please add more details of the error to your question

Comment: When I run the event function the console gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classes')

Comment: Whats the value of `establishments` and `indexc`?